# Why isn't PHP catching a MySQL error?

Tags: php, exception, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'dbname');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

    try 
    {
       $db->begin_transaction();
       $db->query($q_insert_custom);
       $db->commit();
       $error_message = '';
    }
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
       $db->rollback();
       $error_message = $e->getMessage()." **** LINE: ".$e->getLine();
    }

    echo $error_message;
```

There is a problem in `$q_insert_custom` in that it's trying to insert a row but a required field is missing. When you run the query in MySQL Workbench, I get an error about the query and how it's missing the field. But when I run it via PHP is doesn't get caught with exception handling and it appears as if the query ran just fine.

What am I doing wrong? How do I catch when MySQL throws an error about a query?

Comment: How could we know? Whats does `$db->query()` do? It's from `mysqli`?

Comment: Are you sure those MySQLi methods throw exceptions?

Comment: Can you include the code that assigns `$db`? Are you using mysqli?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli

Comment: If it's from `mysqli::query`: **Returns FALSE on failure** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score -1):

A quick way to find MySQL error is to check if there is a message in `$db->error`. Then you can throw it `throw new Exception($db->error);`, if needed.